# CAD secondary development

Tags: autocad, cad

I got some taught about the CAD secondary development.I use a dll 'Teigha' to analysis the dwg file. But there no have any API can get the CAD drawing's xrefs ,so How to got the drawing's xrefs.
I tried to get the xrefs's path and analysis it as a normal drawing(I save the xrefs data to the main drawing (I think when I finished it and it can become one drawing )) but I got nothing.Why?
Then I found even though I got the all data(main drawing and xrefs) I still cannot get the correct data because the xrefs in the main drawing cant copy paste .I cannot get these change,Only I can got the origin xrefs.
 So what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Teigha, you must use the `OdDbXrefGraph.getFrom` method to obtain the graph of the Xrefs. After that, you can explore the graph in a way similar to [this](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/06/finding-all-xrefs-in-the-current-database-using-cnet.html).